# Moshi and Retrofit: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path

Tags: kotlin, http, retrofit, moshi, data-class

I'm using Moshi with Retrofit and trying to query some game data. When I do this I get an error stating the following:

```
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $.errors
```

This seems to point to the `errors` property within the `Games` data class I've created. See here:

```
data class Games(
    val get: String,
    val errors: List<Any?>,
    val results: Long,
    val response: List<GameResponse>,
)

data class GameResponse(
    val game: Game,
    val league: League,
    val teams: Teams,
    val scores: Scores,
)

data class Game(
    val id: Long,
    val stage: String,
    val week: String,
    val date: Date,
    val venue: Venue,
    val status: Status,
)

data class Date(
    val timezone: String,
    val date: String,
    val time: String,
    val timestamp: Long,
)

data class Venue(
    val name: String?,
    val city: Any?,
)

data class Status(
    val short: String,
    val long: String,
    val timer: Any?,
)

data class League(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val season: String,
    val logo: String,
    val country: Country,
)

data class Country(
    val name: String,
    val code: String,
    val flag: String,
)

data class Teams(
    val home: Home,
    val away: Away,
)

data class Home(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val logo: String,
)

data class Away(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val logo: String,
)

data class Scores(
    val home: Home2,
    val away: Away2,
)

data class Home2(
    val quarter1: Long?,
    val quarter2: Long?,
    val quarter3: Long?,
    val quarter4: Long?,
    val overtime: Long?,
    val total: Long?,
)

data class Away2(
    val quarter1: Long?,
    val quarter2: Long?,
    val quarter3: Long?,
    val quarter4: Long?,
    val overtime: Long?,
    val total: Long?,
)
```

When I try making the API call with Postman I get the following response. As a note, I ommited the "parameters" object in my Data Class because I'm passing it as part of the Headers object.

```
    {
    "get": "games",
    "parameters": {
        "date": "2023-11-21"
    },
    "errors": [],
    "results": 1,
    "response": [
        {
            "game": {
                "id": 7693,
                "stage": "Regular Season",
                "week": "Week 11",
                "date": {
                    "timezone": "UTC",
                    "date": "2023-11-21",
                    "time": "01:15",
                    "timestamp": 1700529300
                },
                "venue": {
                    "name": "GEHA Field at Arrowhead Stadium",
                    "city": "Kansas City"
                },
                "status": {
                    "short": "FT",
                    "long": "Finished",
                    "timer": null
                }
            },
            "league": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "NFL",
                "season": "2023",
                "logo": "https://media-4.api-sports.io/american-football/leagues/1.png",
                "country": {
                    "name": "USA",
                    "code": "US",
                    "flag": "https://media-4.api-sports.io/flags/us.svg"
                }
            },
            "teams": {
                "home": {
                    "id": 17,
                    "name": "Kansas City Chiefs",
                    "logo": "https://media-4.api-sports.io/american-football/teams/17.png"
                },
                "away": {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "Philadelphia Eagles",
                    "logo": "https://media-4.api-sports.io/american-football/teams/12.png"
                }
            },
            "scores": {
                "home": {
                    "quarter_1": 7,
                    "quarter_2": 10,
                    "quarter_3": 0,
                    "quarter_4": 0,
                    "overtime": null,
                    "total": 17
                },
                "away": {
                    "quarter_1": 7,
                    "quarter_2": 0,
                    "quarter_3": 7,
                    "quarter_4": 7,
                    "overtime": null,
                    "total": 21
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is how I've structured the Retrofit Service:

```
interface ApiSportsService {
    @GET("random_joke")
    suspend fun getGames(
        @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>
    ): Games

    @GET("status")
    suspend fun getStatus(
        @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>
    ): ApiStatus
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to what I might be doing wrong? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The JSON you posted looks perfectly aligned with the data objects there. Are you sure this is the same JSON you're using with this code? Maybe there's an edge case with your API where errors is a JSON object instead of an array?